Project reactor compatiblity with couchbase
I am using project reactor library, where I am fetching data from couchbase. The retrieval of data from couchbase is taking 2 sec which is causing latency issue.
There is a thread blockage from project reactor which is causing delay.
Instead of project reactor, I tried with spring binder and it was working fine, but I want to use project reactor only and know the issue for thread blocking.
Code:
Reactive<String, data> client;

public Mono<Wrapper> process(Wrapper wrapper) {
    watch.start();
    return client.get(wrapper.getEvent().getId(), Data.class)
            .doOnNext(data -> {
                watch.stop();
                wrapper.setData(Data);
            })
            .thenReturn(wrapper);
}



There are all kinds of ways to shoot yourself in the foot with reactive programming. Can you edit your question to include more details, including a sample of the code you are using for the reactive Couchbase operation?

I have updated the code!

The Reactive class is not part of the Couchbase Java SDK. Can you please share the code that interacts with the Couchbase Java SDK? Ideally, can you share a small, self-contained example that demonstrates the problem, so we can run it on our machines and diagnose the issue you're seeing?

Btw, you start your timer when the method is called, not when you start the request. This would always produce a larger time measurement that it actually is.

@Pokkbeep - please provide code to show what client and for wrapper are.  please provide the code that calls process(wrapper) and calls subscribe (or block).
